# Gutenberg InnerBlock.Content is not being saved or rendered in the front end

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block, acf-gutenberg

I created a custom block for author-bio and i have included the social icons built-in block into my custom block

after importing InnerBlocks into my block js file i have used this code in edit function:

```
<InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={['core/social-links']} />
```

and to display social icons in the frontend i have used this code:

```
<InnerBlocks.Content/>
```

But it saved and rendered only in the editor and does not saved or rendered in the frontend

How to make it rendered and displayed in the frontend

Comment: Could you please post the code of your `save()` function of your custom block? If you are only seeing the content in the Editor, the issue is likely within the `save()` function or the save function is missing/undefined.

Comment: The only line of  code I added to save function is <InnerBlocks.Content/>

Answer (score 0):

The Social Links block actually consists of two blocks: the parent `[core/social-link]` and one or more child `[core/social-links]` blocks. In your `allowedBlocks`, you are restricting the `<InnerBlocks>` to only allow the parent `[core/social-link]` which removes the child blocks from *save()* even if they are defined in the `template`.

Example setup for **edit()**:

```js
import {  useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const SOCIAL_LINKS = [
        ['core/social-links', {}, [
            ['core/social-link', {
                url: "https://wordpress.com/me", // Required to render on frontend
                service: "wordpress",            // **
                label: "WordPress"
            }],
            ['core/social-link', {
                url: "https://example.com",      // Required to render on frontend
                service: "chain",                // **
                label: "My Site"
            }],
            ]
        ]];
        
    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <InnerBlocks
                allowedBlocks={['core/social-links', 'core/social-link']} // Parent & Child
                template={SOCIAL_LINKS}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```